# jquery checkbox multipile disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three checkboxes. What I want to do is when I click on one checkbox, that specific checkbox should disable.

Here is my code for the checkbox:

```
<input type='checkbox'
    name='checkboxStudents'
    id='checkBoxStudents'
    />
```

Comment: it cannot be uncheck if it is disabled it is not a user friendly interface in that sense

Comment: Please include the definition of `function checkedFunction()`.

Comment: Hi Peter B Sorry Adding The checkedFunction() was a mistake I have edited my question now

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "input[name='checkboxStudents']").click(function(event){
$(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

one <input type='checkbox'
    name='checkboxStudents'
    id='checkBoxStudents1' />

two <input type='checkbox'
    name='checkboxStudents'
    id='checkBoxStudents2' />
    
three <input type='checkbox'
    name='checkboxStudents'
    id='checkBoxStudents3' />
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan Dellinger On My Website I Have Multiple Checkboxes And When I Click On One Checkbox It Disables But When I Try To Click On The Other Checkboxes they don't disable

Comment: Hi Bryan Dellinger thank you it works but it only selects two of the checkboxes and leaves out the one last checkbox

Comment: are you running the code snippet? all three are disabled after you click. if you have further requirements why don't you make a fiddle to illustrate your problem